# required size of a configuration file for a HX1K (in "SPI slave" mode)

Tags: embedded, yosys

I am reworking the programmer for the Olimex iCE40HX1K board (targetted towards a STM32F103 ma) where I also would like to implement the "SPI Slave" mode to configure an image directly into RAM without using the serial flash.

Looking at the Lattice "programming and Configuration guide" (page 11), it is noted in table 8 that a EPROM for a ICE40-LP/LX1K must be at least 34112 bytes. (which -I guess- means that the configuration-files can be up to that size).
However, all images I have (sofar) created with the icestorm tools are 32220 octets.

I am a bit puzzled here.
Can somebody explain the difference between these two figures?

Does the HX1K need a configuration-file of 32220 or 34112 bytes?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Lattice arrived at this number. A complete HX1K bin file with BRAM initialization but without comment and without multiboot header is 32220 bytes in size. The (optional) multiboot header would add another 160 bytes (32220 + 160 = 32380). The lattice tools usually add about 80 bytes to the comment field (32220 + 80 = 32300). Whatever I do, all numbers I have are more than 1000 short of 34112.

I don't know if there is a maximum length for the comment. Maybe there is and 34112 is the size of a bit stream with a comment of maximum length?

34112 - 32220 = 1892. Maybe someone decided to add 8kB (8192 bytes) just in case, but that person accidentally swapped the first two digits? Idk..

If you don't care about comments or multiboot headers, then iCE40 1K bit-streams have a fixed size, and that size is 32220 bytes.